# Adding description text below Fancybox rather than use title attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

Is there any way to perhaps add text in a Fancybox box rather than having to use the title attribute? To illustrate the problem I'm having, here's one of the pictures displayed on my page which uses Fancybox:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12453703/fbox01.PNG

As you see, for the title attribute I have put in HTML so that the picture title is a link to a webpage. It looks good and it works just fine. However, the bad thing is, when I point to the thumbnail for the Fancybox, I get the raw HTML code:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12453703/fbox02.png

Is there some workaround for this? Have the HTML link in the enlarged image, but simply have text for the thumbnail tooltip which pops up? Or perhaps (as my title suggests), have some seperate text below the image which is seperate from the caption text?

(I didn't find anything useful regarding this issue in the Fancybox docs but I could be wrong.)

Thanks.

- Edit, the code I'm using at the moment is quite simple:

```js
$("a.single_image").fancybox(
{
    transitionIn: 'elastic',
    transitionOut: 'elastic',
    easingIn: 'easeInOutBack',
    easingOut: 'easeOutBack',
    speedIn: 300,
    speedOut: 300,
    cyclic: true    ,
    titlePosition: 'over',
});
```

Comment: You can force `title` for each of your image, can you post the code where u r defining the fancybox?
http://fancybox.net/api to `Advanced Options`

Comment: Just looking at advanced options now, seeing how I can use that to fix my issue. I'll post the code in a sec (I'll edit my original post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new `attribute` for your link, I will just call it `rel`:

```
<a href="myimg.jpg" class="single_image" rel="My Title"><img src="myimg.jpg" /></a>

$("a.single_image").each(function(){
    $(this).fancybox({
        transitionIn: 'elastic',
        transitionOut: 'elastic',
        easingIn: 'easeInOutBack',
        easingOut: 'easeOutBack',
        speedIn: 300,
        speedOut: 300,
        cyclic: true    ,
        titlePosition: 'over',
        title:  $(this).attr('rel')
    });
})
```

Comment: Thanks - hmm, I seem to be nearly there, but I've broken my Fancybox now - here's the code of one of the images:

<a class="single_image" rel="&lt;a href=&quot;image.jpg&quot;&gt;image&lt;/a&gt;" href="http://www.mediaite.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/colbertSUperPAC.jpg" title="colbert super pac">


What you're seeing in the rel attribute is encoded HTML, but now when I click the thumbnail the Fancybox isn't popping up... weird.

Comment: are you adding these links dynamically from server site?

Comment: Yep, I'm doing it from PHP, using htmlentities($url) for the rel attribute. If I use a plain text rel value like "test" or "hello" the Fancybox pops up just fine with the caption, but I'd really like that caption to be a URL instead.

Comment: alright, instead of writing it in `rel tag` you can just directly generate it as part of script to replace: `title:  $(this).attr('rel')` :/

Comment: Woot! Thanks for the advice, it worked. What I did was, have PHP generate a span element after each picture, I then used jQuery to get the next sibling after each picture, and grab the span's title attribute, and now it works... Seems like a bit more work than usual but I'm happy. :)

Comment: Cool mate, a better way was to add as `html` instead of `title` attribute for the span, anyway both are gonna work :)

Comment: You mean grab the inner html of the span with html()? If you meant that, it didn't work for some reason, the URL was displayed as raw text, but for some reason slapping it inside the title attrib worked